# SpringMVC Upload file across servers Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I want to to build a file upload across server in SpringMVC.But when i test,page will be status 500 and say

`Handler dispatch failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers`
`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    *** a lot of`

In the root cause point out Exception line of my code at loveandpeace.uploadController.upload(uploadController.java:48)

this is the code

```
47 Client client = Client.create();

48 WebResource webResource = client.resource(path + fileName);
```

It`s two project on two tomcat of my computer

I use the jar is jarsey-bundle,And i had try use jsr311-api-1.1.1 to fix thee Providers not found.

Change tomcat conf/web.xml readonly be false,and make path-way is real exist in IntellJ out directory

But those all are failed :(

Page status 500 still there,hope u can help QAQ

I haven`t use maven, those jar is what I use

commons-fileupload-1.4.jar

commons-io-2.6.jar

jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar

jackson-core-2.9.8.jar

jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar

jersey-bundle-1.13-b01.jar

jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar(try used)

And Spring 5.2.3 release

Comment: share the dependencies please.

Comment: I update at the question describ

Answer (score 0):

After 3hour I find this solution for myself :D

1.I use the wrong function,in the 48 line with resource()

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(path + fileName);
```

I should use resource(String) replace resource(URL),this is the same name but different variable

2.I find my class file not in out directory,With rebuild Artifacts will be OK.

3.In the new Artifacts directory,IntellJ don`t create uploads directory for me.

I create one with basic Windows way.
Then,the Upload file across servers in SpringMVC is working.

By the way I want to thanks Sagar Kharab spend time watch this prob,U are my first guy on StackOverFlow :D